# Select no muestra campo vacío

Tags: select, null

Tengo la tabla cliente que esta así
id    nombre  apellido
1    c1          c1
2    c2          c2
3    c3

pero al hacer el select muestra:
id    nombre  apellido
1    c1          c1
2    c2          c2

probé con IS NOT NULL, con LENGTH y otros googleando pero no me a servido.

Comment: y cuál es el query que estás ejecutando?

Comment: Pasa si puedes la consulta, y la estructura de la tabla

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta es muy poco clara. no podemos adivinar porque te sale un registro menos sin conocer las tablas y sin saber que query hiciste. Por favor usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion que falta. Cuando lo hagas, deja un comentario con mi nombre (usa @gbianchi) y vuelvo a abrir tu pregunta.

Comment: @PakLeiChong probe asi: select id, nombre, apellido from datos group by nombre orde by id desc